# Metrics elasticsearch successful requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, monitoring

Is it possible to have some metrics about how many search requests were processed over a certain time on ElasticSearch at AWS? Something like the cloudwatch monitoring for Cloudsearch that you can check the number of successful requests per minute (RPM):

[image: Cloudsearch successful RPM]

Answer (score 0):

Just find out the endpoint `_stats` that allow user to retrieve interesting metrics, so basically you will have to divide `indices.search.query_total` for `indices.search.query_time_in_millis` to have an average time for each query.

Still don't know a good way to have a real time data to plot a monitoring graph

[Source #1](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitor-elasticsearch-performance-metrics/#toc-search-performance-metrics)

[Source #2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html)